# Trying to access varibles from another script

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Projectile : MonoBehaviour  
{

    Weapon weapon;

    void Start()
    {
        Weapon weapon = GameObject.Find("Thing").GetComponent<Weapon>();
    }

    void Update()
    {

    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        other.gameObject.GetComponent<EnemyHealth>().TakeDamage(weapon.damage);
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

Comment: what are you asking? You cant access `EnemyHealth` or something else?

Comment: Please add some details about your problem and the error you get when running your code.

Comment: 1.  Please explain what and where your error is occurring, and
2.  You've re-declared `weapon` inside `Start` such that it hides the class-level field which will always be null (like when you get into `OnTriggerEnter`).

Comment: I'm trying to get varibles from the weapon script but now it's saying null reference. I want to get the damage varible from my weapon script.

Answer (score 0):

you are declaring the weapon again, in local scope, it gets assigned but gets eaten by the garbage collector as soon you leave the method body. just replace Weapon weapon with weapon, this will tell the compiler you are accessing an existing variable not creating a throwaway one

Try this instead for Start

```
    void Start()
    {
     var thing=GameObject.Find("Thing");
     if (thing==null) Debug.Log("Thing object not found");
      else
      {   
         weapon = thing.GetComponent<Weapon>();
         if (weapon==null) 
        Debug.Log("No weapon found on thing;
      }
    }
```

Comment: I now get nullreferenceException: Object referen not set to an instance of an object.